# Classes in the same package not communicating with each other

Tags: java, swing

I just started working on a Snake game, and I made a Main class, and I made a Display class immediately. I created a package, "Game" for them, but when I compile the Main class, the console says it can't find "Display."

Here is the Main class:

```
package Game;

public class Main {
public static Display f = new Display();

public static int w = 700;
public static int h = 400;

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    f.setTitle("  SNAKE");
    f.setSize(w, h);
} // end of method main()
} // end of class Main
```

Here is the Display class (not completed):

```
package Game;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Display extends JFrame {
public Display() {

} // end of constructor
} // end of class Display
```

Comment: You should compile `Display` first to be able to compile `Main`...Please use a **proper** IDE, and no notepad, and the like.

Comment: Also package name should be in lower case.

Comment: Show us your directory structure and the commands you ran, in steps.

Comment: Exactly how are you compiling? From command line, or using an IDE?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the directory structure to be :

```
                 Project
                    |
         -------------------------
         |                       |
       source
         |                      build (this is where compiled stuff will go or resources)
    ------------
    |          |
Main.java    Display.java
```

Now from the command prompt, go to `Project` Directory and write :

```
javac -d build source\*.java
```

This will create the `package folders` inside the `build` folder automatically (In this case `Game` Folder will be created automatically containing `Display.class` and `Main.class`). Now go into the `build` folder and run it like this :

```
java Game.Main
```

More information regarding the use of `javac` can be found, by simply typing `javac` on the terminal. All options with which `javac` can be used with, will be displayed on the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure both classes are located in a directory named `Game` as expected by the compiler.

Side note:
- Follow Java [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) for package names and use *lowercase* letters, e.g. `game` rather than `Game`

Answer (score -1):

That package name looks very odd. Try something like com.liamslagle.game instead.

Comment: there is something we called comment,you can try it :)